# custom phong shader envMap flipped

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

I use a ShaderMaterial that is a complete copy of the default Phong shader (I use shaderChunks).

My problem is that the `envMap` is flipped over X...

Here is what I get:

[image: what I get]

And what I want:

[image: what I want]

I tried to access `cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture` to use `repeat.x = -1` and `wrapS = THREERepeatWrapping.RepeatWrapping` but it does absolutely nothing...

```
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.01, 500, 256);
scene.add(cubeCamera);

var sphereMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
        THREE.UniformsLib.common,
        THREE.UniformsLib.aomap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.lightmap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.emissivemap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.bumpmap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.normalmap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.displacementmap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.fog,
        THREE.UniformsLib.lights,
        THREE.UniformsLib.shadowmap,
        {
            emissive: {
                type: "c",
                value: new THREE.Color(0x000000)
            },
            specular: {
                type: "c",
                value: new THREE.Color(0x111111)
            },
            shininess: {
                type: "f",
                value: 30
            },
            envMap: {
                type: "t",
                value: cubeCamera.renderTarget
            }
        }
    ]),
    vertexShader: require("../../shaders/phong.vert.glsl"),
    fragmentShader: require("../../shaders/phong.frag.glsl"),
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    depthWrite: false,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 1,
    lights: true
});

sphereMaterial.envMap = true;
```

**EDIT:**

[JSFIDDLE example](https://jsfiddle.net/hndth2jy/3/)

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that [MeshPhongMaterial](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.js) sets alot of parameters when it is instantiated? maybe `this.reflectivity = 1;`. Just my first thought.

Comment: Nope, envMap still flipped horizontaly...

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a ShaderMaterial  instead of just a MeshPhoneMaterial?

Comment: I want to make a custom shader after that... But I cant make envMap work, so I cant progress...

Comment: ok, I will add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the reflection you are after, set

```
sphereShaderMaterial.uniforms.flipEnvMap.value = 1;
```

I'm not sure when this actually gets set on the MeshPhongMaterial, I suspect somewhere in the WebGLRenderer it does some checks and sets this. The WebGLRenderer does many things to the different types of materials which makes them a little hard to just extend easily.

Comment: That's working! Many thanks for your help!
Here is the jsfiddle of working version: https://jsfiddle.net/hndth2jy/4/